# How do I add separators in the footer (containing the total value of each column) of my reactable table in r?

Tags: r, reactable

I have built a table using the reactable package in RStudio. The first column contains text and all the others contain monetary values. I have added a footer which contains the total of each column except the first. For the body of the table, I added separators to the numbers (because they are large numbers) using

colDef(format = colFormat(prefix = "£", separators = TRUE, digits = 2)

but this does not apply to the footer and I can't find out how to get the numbers in the footer in the same format.  The footer was made using

sprintf("£%.2f", sum(values))

and so has the correct prefix and decimal places, but not the separators. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the separator in the footer function. I use the following method with the `prettyNum` function:

```
    colDef(format = colFormat(prefix = "£", separators = TRUE, digits = 2), # format rest of columns
           footer = function(values) prettyNum(sprintf("£%.2f", sum(values)), big.mark = ",", preserve.width = "none")  # format footer
```

There is also the `scales` library, I don't use it but many others do. You might look into that as well.